# mod_rewrite not working to change URL

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to change dynamic URL's to URL's more acceptable by search engines.
For example change this :

> http://myurl.com.au/page.php?id=100&name=myname

to

> http://myurl.com.au/100/myname.php

or .html at the end it does not matter.

I am using Apache 2.2. I am not using `.htaccess` rather I put my code in `/etc/httpd/conf/vhosts/myfile`
but it does not work, the URL does not change at all.

```
Options Indexes Includes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /page.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

Either your have the wrong description in your question or your rule is backwards. Maybe this could work:

```
Options Indexes Includes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/page\.php /%1/%2.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your code and it does not work either, the URL does not change after refreshing browser. The RewriteRule that I have I got from a mod_rewrite generator website [link](http://www.generateit.net/).  Also I do not understand what you mean by me having the wrong description in my question, what is wrong with it?

Comment: Your rule is trying to rewrite http://myurl.com.au/100/myname.php to http://myurl.com.au/page.php?id=100&name=myname. In your question you say you want to do the opposite.

Comment: If it's not changing I guess you could try the `R` flag. Also, enabling logging is a good thing when troubleshooting `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Qben you are absolutely right, I think I had a small brain freeze. I later realised everything and it is now working as expected for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question, and accept the answer for future references. :)

Answer (score 0):

After doing some further testing it turns out that I do have the right code.  I just don't have my head screwed on and was not thinking. Expecting that the mod_rewrite would magically change the URL to symbolic links when it is actually doing the reverse of that. It is all working for me now.